# @RolesAllowed always rejected (forbidden) on Jersey resource

Tags: java, rest, authentication, jersey, jax-rs

I am attempting to set up authentication based on roles for a resource I am exposing via Jersey/JAX-RS.  This resource exists within a Glassfish instance in which authentication based on roles (specifically, via @RolesAllowed) is currently working as desired.  I'm running Jersey within a servlet container:

```
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
```

And am enforcing basic auth on my resource; that requirement is being enforced as expected.  I have also provided the following initialization parameter to Jersey:

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

However, when I attempt to actually add an @RolesAllowed annotation, all accesses fail.  For example:

```
@Path("/my/resource")
@ManagedBean
@RolesAllowed({"SYSTEM"})
public class Resource {
    // Accesses with credentials for a user that has the SYSTEM role fail!
}
```

If I inject a security context and call context.isUserInRole(), it returns false for all roles.  What's very strange is that if I remove my @RolesAllowed annotation for this resource,  and make requests with valid credentials, this class can successfully access EJB's which require that the user be in the same role I was originally trying to test for.  It seems approximately like Jersey may be authenticating with the wrong SecurityContext, or some such.  Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: how are users granted roles and are the roles appropriately mapped (see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/security-intro005.htm#BNBXJ) for reference)?

Answer (score 10):

I struggled with a similar issue for hours before one line from [this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Fae%2Ftwbs_jaxrs_impl_securejaxrs_webcont.html) IBM article opened my eyes. Surprisingly, not a single book or user guide mentions this critical fact, without which, authentication can't succeed.

When using annotation-based security, **web.xml is not optional**; quite on the contrary, `<security-constraint>` element must be present; the web container checks for security before JAX-RS does and without a `<security-constraint>`, the proper security context is not set. Thus when JAX-RS invokes `isUserInRole(role)`, it always returns false.

In addition, either `<security-role>` element(s) in web.xml or `@DeclareRoles` annotation must be present.

Lastly, if using Jersey, `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature` needs to be registered in the Application class to enable annotation-based security.

HTH others who struggle with the pathetic documentation, or lack of it, thereof, that's out there.

Comment: Yes, you are quite right!  I discovered the same, that I needed to set a security constraint in order to have a proper context.  Thanks!