# @RolesAllowed etc. without web.xml

Tags: java, jax-rs, web.xml, ejb-3.1

I am currently working on a quite modular application where we have many jars that will be packaged and glued together in a war file.

Some of these jar files have REST resources that want to be secured. Common way is the @RolesAllowed annotation etc.

From my current knowledge this implies an existing web.xml in the WAR. This way we would have to implement jar-specific information (e.g. context roots) inside the WAR, not in the place where it belongs.

Like the most things nowadays - is there a way to programmatically set up security contexts etc. without a web.xml?

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict access to your REST resources by registering [`RolesAllowedDynamicFeature`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/filter/RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.html) in your REST configuration class that extends from [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html)

```
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {
  public ApplicationConfig() {
    super(ApplicationConfig.class);
    register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
  }
}
```

So you can use your application roles on your resources methods like this

```
import javax.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext;

@Path("secured")
@PermitAll
public class SecuredResource {

  @GET
  @Path("user")
  @RolesAllowed("user")
  public String user(@Context SecurityContext sc) {
    boolean test = sc.isUserInRole("user");
    return (test) ? "true": "false";
  }

  @GET
  @Path("admin")
  @RolesAllowed("admin")
  public String admin(@Context SecurityContext sc) {
    boolean test = sc.isUserInRole("admin");
    return (test) ? "true": "false";
  }
}
```

Jersey documentation has more details on securing REST resources using annotations here

https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/security.html#d0e12428

Answer (score 1):

I've not worked with JAX-RS for a while, but the last time I checked, when using annotation-based security, web.xml is not optional.

See my answer for details.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20023018/839733